# Gentoo No rule to make target 'olddefconfig'

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, gentoo, uefi

I have been following this guide from the gentto wiki to install Gentoo. I have hit a bit of a roadblock though which looks reasonably simple but I am having trouble figuring it out.

On this page: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Configuring_Secure_Boot#test_secure_boot

In the Testing Secure Boot with a Signed Kernel section whilst executing the buildkernel command I get the following error:

```
* Updating old config using make olddefconfig
make: *** No rule to make target 'olddefconfig'.  Stop.
* buildkernel: Error: Caught signal - exiting
```

I don't seem to have an olddefconfig at all and even if I did have one I am not entirely sure what rule should be added to the make file.

I have read the man page for the buildkernel command and gone over this description [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Configuring_and_Building_the_Kernel#What_the_buildkernel_Script_Does_.28Background_Reading.29) but sadly I have still not managed to fix the issue.

Does anyone know how to rectify this error?

Answer (score 2):

So I now have an answer for this. It sometimes happens when the kernel sources have been updated to a new version, but the symbolic link /usr/src/linux hasn't been updated to
match. Gentoo leaves a partially populated kernel source tree in
/usr/src/linux--genoo even when an old kernel source version is
unmerged, and if the symbolic link /usr/src/linux still points to this.

if you run:

```
eselect kernel list
```

and it produces something like:

```
Available kernel symlink targets:
  [1]   linux-4.14.63-gentoo-r1
```

and

```
ls -l /usr/src/
```

produces something along the lines of:

```
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   20 Aug 18 00:33 linux -> linux-4.14.61-gentoo
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Aug 18 02:38 linux-4.14.61-gentoo
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Aug 18 02:33 linux-4.14.63-gentoo-r1
```

Running the following command will update the symbolic link and let you get on with things.

```
eselect kernel set 1
```

I emailed the author of the guide to get this information so credit goes to her. I am leaving this here in case anyone else runs into this problem in future.